# CSS Table Height Suddenly Stopped Working In Various Browsers

Tags: html, css, html-table

I haven't printed a calendar in several months, but now it no longer honors the CSS height attribute like it used to. The `height` attribute works fine in the browser (screen) but not when printing. I've tried fixed height, percentage, and even `100vw` I saw in another post, adding `<section/>` tags, etc. to no avail. It stopped working in Chrome, Edge, even Brave all around the same time more or less. It *does* still work in Firefox. Even boiling it down to a fairly simple page it's not working http://DatesAndTimes.com/dates/test.html.

[image: CSS height is ignored, resulting in table being collapsed to minimum size allowed by the text in the cells of each row]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <style>
table {
   width: 100%;
   height: 900px;
}
table > thead > tr > th {
   border-style: outset;
   border-color: #333333;
   text-align: center;
}
table > tbody > tr > td {
   border-style: inset;
   border-color: #333333;
   text-align: right;
}
table > tbody > tr.new-page {
   page-break-before: always;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr><th>Row ?</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>Page 1 Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Page 1 Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="new-page"><td>Page 2 Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Page 2 Row 2</td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Is there a new way to get a table to fill up each page?

Comment: Could you describe what ' not working' means a bit more? I've just tried a print on Edge and it works fine. (A4 paper size - what size are you printing on?).

Comment: `table > body > tr.new-page` is nonsensical. Guess you mean `tbody`not `body`

Comment: @user3342816 Thanks. I fixed the body -> tbody issue in both the post above and the http://DatesAndTimes.com/dates/test.html one.

Comment: @AHaworth By "not working" I mean that "now it no longer honors the CSS height attribute like it used to". The table is collapsed to the minimum size allowed by the text in the cells of each row. I added a screen capture to the post, from the Edge browser. The paper size is "Letter (8 1/2 x 11 in)". Since it's working for you, it makes me wonder if the Epson printer driver updated and is now fouling up the table height - would explain affecting all browsers. Except that Firefox is OK.

Comment: This is how it renders for print in FireFox (2 pages): https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZAut.png . You want the rows to be evenly spread spanning entire height of pages? I.e. from sample page; page 1: 3 rows spanning 100% height, Page2: 3 rows spanning 100% height

Comment: Not sure if what you want; but you could wrap each section into it's own `<tbody>` instead of usgin break on `tr` and use something like `@media print {  html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }  table { height: calc(100% - 40px);  }  tbody {  height: 100%; page-break-after: always;  }  thead  { height: 20px;  } }` - which could be improved; but as a start.

Comment: Giving: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcSuR.png